# Route 404 error Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm experiencing an error I don't quite understand.  The route seems to be working fine on my development machine(which is windows 10, php 7) but gives 404 error on shared linux hosting.

Below is the code:

**The route**

```
 Auth::routes();
Route::get('/curries','CurriessController@index')->name('curries');
Route::resource('/curries','CurriesController');
```

**The Link**

```
 <td><a href="/curries/{{$curry->id}}"> {{$curry->curry_title}}</a></td>
```

I also tried`route('curry.index', $curry->id`

What makes no sense to me is that it works on windows but the 404 on linux.  Please assist

Comment: It looks like you are making use of a `resource` route. This could throw a 404 for some routes when the model is not found in your databse. Could you trace where this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the Model exists
2. Make sure the table exists in the database
3. replace your link with `<td><a href="{{route('curries.index')}}/{{$curry->id}}">Type of Curry</a></td>`

This should work